# Matplotlib: Turning axes off and setting facecolor at the same time not possible?

Tags: python, matplotlib

can someone explain why this simple code wont execute the facecolor command while setting the axis off?

```
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(211, facecolor=(0,0,0), aspect='equal')
ax.scatter(np.random.random(10000), np.random.random(10000), c="gray", s=0.25)
ax.axes.set_axis_off()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, you made the axes including the facecolor invisible. You could try `fig.set_facecolor(...)` or add a rectangle patch filled with the desired color.

Comment: To fill the axes background `ax.imshow([[0]], extent=[*ax.get_xlim(), *ax.get_ylim()], cmap='gray', zorder=0)` might also work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The background patch is part of the axes. So if the axes is turned off, so will the background patch.

Some options:

#### Re-add the background patch

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(211, facecolor=(0,0,0), aspect='equal')
ax.set_axis_off()
ax.add_artist(ax.patch)
ax.patch.set_zorder(-1)
```

#### Create new patch

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(211, facecolor=(0,0,0), aspect='equal')
ax.set_axis_off()
ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((0,0), 1, 1, facecolor=(0,0,0),
                           transform=ax.transAxes, zorder=-1))
```

#### Turn axis spines and ticks invisible

...but keep the axis on.

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(211, facecolor=(0,0,0), aspect='equal')
for spine in ax.spines.values():
    spine.set_visible(False)
ax.tick_params(bottom=False, labelbottom=False,
               left=False, labelleft=False)
```